# Download PDF with Python from REST API with auth key

Tags: python, rest, pdf, https

I have access to an API which successfuly returns an answer which contains a link to download a pdf. However, I don't see how to now download the pdf and save it without doing a second request. Let me show you what I mean.

```
import requests

params = ("USERNAME1234", "PASSWORD1234")

resp = requests.get("https://API.EXAMPLE.com/sub/sub/file", auth = params)
```

At that point, if I print the content of the request and the status code, I get

```
> print(resp.content)
  [
    {
      "Parameter1": "Param1",
      "Parameter2": 222222,
      "Parameter3": "2022-11-01",
      "Parameter4": "2022-11-01 21:16:32",
      "Parameter5": "Param5",
      "Parameter6": [],
      "Parameter7": "https://API.EXAMPLE.com/sub/sub/ABCDEFG?testPath=testAPI",
      "Parameter8": "Param8",
      "Attachments": [
        {
          "Parameter9.1": "Param9.1",
          "FileExtension": "pdf",
          "Url": "https://API.EXAMPLE.com/sub/sub/ABCDEFG.pdf?testPath=testAPI"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
> print(resp.status_code)
  200
```

I could perfectly locate this "Url", download, and save the pdf with Python, but I find it cumbersome. I am hopeful that there is something more direct but I could not find it in the doc or on the forum.